# how to set a range to extract the information I want to get?

Tags: c++, regex

I am trying to extract a ragne of information from the data.
for example,

```
[student1]
id: 001
name:red
surname:brown
phone number:0123456
address: blabla
```

from this data (it's text file), I want to extract all information of this student using regular expression, just by putting in student number 001.

here is the code i tried.

```
  ifstream file (filename);
  string line;
  bool found = false;
  regex format("[0-9]{3}");
  regex name("^name:");
  if (regex_search(id, format)) {
    regex Id("^id: "+id);
    if (file.is_open()) {
      while ( getline (file,line)) {
        if (regex_search(line, Id)) {
          found = true;
        } else if ( found && regex_search(line, name) ) {
          return line;
          break;
        }
      }
    } else {
      return "Sorry, can not open file.";
    }
    file.close();
  } 
  return("");
}
```

so far, I succeded to extract specific information like name or surname etc.. but not every information.
My idea is modifing the part of regex name with bracket "[]" to extract a range of string on that code. but...failed.

Comment: Why do you want to use a regex? You know the exact structure of the data.

Comment: @ThomasSablik cuz its part of my exam haha...

Comment: How is the usage of regex specified in your exam? It's absolutely not necessary here so more information is needed to answer. Why would you use a regex instead of `substr(4,3)`? That will extract the student id

Comment: @ThomasSablik using substr(4,3), can I extract whole information of that student by putting in student id?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Where does `id` come from? The question is not completely clear for me. How is the file structured? How do you read the file? If you read it line by line you can't extract all information at once.

Comment: @ThomasSablik I used commandline and compiled it like g++ filename.cpp -o go && go getName 001    that code's function name is getName sorry

Comment: How is the input file structured? Please provide a [mcve] that can be copied, pasted and compiled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the file and use the following regular expression on the content. With [`regex_search`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_search) you can search for the student and iterate over the groups.

You can use this regex to find the student and extract its data:

```
\[student\w+\]\nid: *001\nname: *(\w*)\nsurname: *(\w*)\nphone number: *(\w*)\naddress: *(\w*)
```

E.g. for

```
[student0]
id: 000
name:red
surname:brown
phone number:0123456
address: blabla
[student1]
id: 001
name:red
surname:brown
phone number:0123456
address: blabla
[student2]
id: 002
name:red
surname:brown
phone number:0123456
address: blabla
```

it will match

```
[student1]
id: 001
name:red
surname:brown
phone number:0123456
address: blabla
```

and the groups contain

`red`, `brown`, `0123456` and `blabla`.

A good online tool to work with regular expressions is https://regexr.com/5891j

You can assign the id you are looking for to variable `id` and build the regex string with:

```
R"(\[student\w+\]\nid: *)"s + id + R"(\nname: *(\w*)\nsurname: *(\w*)\nphone number: *(\w*)\naddress: *(\w*))"s;
```

An example code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>
using std::literals::string_literals::operator""s;

int main() {
    std::string id = "001";
    std::regex regex((R"(\[student\w+\]\nid: *)"s + id + R"(\nname: *(\w*)\nsurname: *(\w*)\nphone number: *(\w*)\naddress: *(\w*))"s).c_str());
    std::ifstream file("data.txt");
    if (!file) return EXIT_FAILURE;
    
    std::string content{std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(file), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()};
    std::smatch matches;
    if (std::regex_search(content, matches, regex)) {
        std::cout << "Student data:\n" << matches[0] << "\n\n";
        std::cout << "Id: " << id << '\n';
        std::cout << "Name: " << matches[1] << '\n';
        std::cout << "Surname: " << matches[2] << '\n';
        std::cout << "Phone: " << matches[3] << '\n';
        std::cout << "Address: " << matches[4] << '\n';
    }
}
```

Example output:

```
Student data:
[student1]
id: 001
name:red
surname:brown
phone number:0123456
address: blabla

Id: 001
Name: red
Surname: brown
Phone: 0123456
Address: blabla
```